# QuickFIX initiator certificates are not required to establish SSL communication with the acceptor

Tags: ssl, quickfix

I've been working on a client API using QuickFIX and I'm planning to use SSL and certificate based authentication. I generated self signed certificates for acceptor and initiator the following way:

1) Generate and export server/acceptor certificate:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias server -keystore server.jks
keytool -export -alias server -file server.cer -keystore server.jks
```

2) Generate and export client/initiator certificate:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias client -keystore client.jks
keytool -export -alias client -file client.cer -keystore client.jks
```

3) Import server/acceptor certificate to client keystore:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server -file server.cer -keystore client.jks
```

4) Import client/initiator certificate to server/acceptor keystore:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias client -file client.cer -keystore server.jks
```

Acceptor config:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=server.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=password
```

Initiator config:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=client.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=password
```

Everything seems to work fine and data is getting encrypted. However, if I remove the initiator's client.jks keystore file, I will get a QuickFIX log entry saying *"client.jks: keystore not found, using empty keystore"*. Strange thing, the initiator is still able to connect and establish a valid FIX session. I would expected the connection to be dropped immediately since no valid certificate is provided. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client certificate is not required by default, you must set this:
NeedClientAuth=Y

Comment: Your answer is valid although QuickFIX did not support client certificate authentication until https://www.quickfixj.org/jira/browse/QFJ-821